# Get information from Yahoo Finance

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I want to get the Market Cap value from this site using importxml:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KIT.OL?p=KIT.OL&.tsrc=fin-srch

Where it says 3.217B.

I am using this to get the "previous close" value:

```
=ImportXML("https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&B3&"/history?p="&B3; "//tbody/tr[1]/td[6]")
```

I was hoping I could just adjust the above formula to get te market cap value. Anyone who can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//tr"), 9, 2)
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//tr")), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'Market Cap'", 0))
```

[image]

---

---

## however!

this way you can get only the old value. to get the new one you will need to use a script:

```
function YAHOO(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  const tables = [...res.getContentText().matchAll(/(<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>)/g)];
  if (tables.length < 2) return "No tables. Please confirm URL again.";
  const values = tables.reduce((ar, [,table]) => {
    if (table) {
      const root = XmlService.parse(table).getRootElement();
      const temp = root.getChild("tbody", root.getNamespace()).getChildren().map(e => e.getChildren().map(f => isNaN(f.getValue()) ? f.getValue() : Number(f.getValue())));
      ar = ar.concat(temp);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  return values[0].map((_, i) => values.map(r => r[i]));
}
```

and formula:

```
=INDEX(YAHOO(A1), 2, 9)
```

[image]

extra reading: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/65914858/5632629**

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the full XPath:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span")
```

Or you could try a `vlookup()`:

```
=vlookup("Market Cap", IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr"),2,0)
```