Google Sheets ImportXML returns "Resource at URL not found" for yahoo finance (stocks with ".")
I have been trying to make a google sheet portfolio with international stocks. I have managed with using the "googlefinance" formula, but it does not cover a lot of international (outside of US) stocks. So I have been trying to adapt it with the XPath and yahoo finance. Unfortunately I have again found that I have some limitations with the stocks.
Tested TICKERS (ORCL NVDA LUNR SHELL.AS SIE.DE NESN.SW MSFT TSLA NSRGY NESM.F AAPL.NE ENR.DE AAPL)
The formula I am using is: =index(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&A11,"//*[@class='livePrice svelte-mgkamr']//span"),1).
The thing that I see is that when the link has "SMTH.SM" it does not work. Otherwise it does. BUT one thing is bugging me - SIE.DE is working just fine somehow.
Any ideas? I hope that I will be able to pull out info even for stocks with dot in their name.
I have tried to use the link as it is (for example https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SHELL.AS) instead of the cell and it still doesn't work.

try:
function YAHOO(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  const htmlContent = res.getContentText();

  // Use regex to find the specific span element containing the price
  const regex = /<span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/g;
  let match;
  let price = "Price not found.";

  while ((match = regex.exec(htmlContent)) !== null) {
    if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    // Check if this span matches the specific path by its surrounding elements
    const precedingText = htmlContent.substring(0, match.index);
    const followingText = htmlContent.substring(match.index + match[0].length);

    if (precedingText.includes('<fin-streamer') && followingText.includes('</fin-streamer>')) {
      price = match[1];
      break;
    }
  }

  return price;
}

as import formula can be off (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66064380/5632629)


then, all of them you can get with simple LAMBDA:
=BYROW(A4:A16, LAMBDA(x, YAHOO("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&x)))



Amazing! Is there a way to get hold of the dividend data like that? I find it hard yet to understand the code and can't do it myself yet.

@DarinaDimitrova you mean Forward Dividend & Yield? should be doable. please close this question (you may accept the answer if it solved your issue) and open new one for dividend
